# JS: Touch event exponentially increases each time

Tags: javascript

I am using a touch event to determine a left or right swipe on the image.  The issue that when I swipe, it fires many times and automatically goes to the end when swiping right and the beginning when swiping right.  What is the best way to handle this?

EDIT: It works now that I put the logic in the `touchend` and compared the starting point with the ending point but now each time I touch, the `touchend` event runs an extra time.

The first, I see it once.  The next swipe, I see it run 3 times, the following time, 6 times, the time after that 10.  Seems like it's incremeneting each time.

```
const eventTouchStart = carouselImagesContainer.addEventListener('touchstart', (evt) => {
    startingPoint = evt.changedTouches[0].screenX;
    console.log("I AM STARTING")
    carouselImagesContainer.addEventListener('touchmove', (evt2) => {
        console.log("I AM MOVING");
    })
    carouselImagesContainer.addEventListener('touchend', (evt2) => {
        let endPoint = evt2.changedTouches[0].screenX;
        let total = endPoint - startingPoint;
        console.log("I AM ENDING", total)

        if (Math.abs(total) < 50) {
            return;
        }
        if (total > 0) {
            console.log("GO 1 SLIDE BACK")
            window.requestAnimationFrame(carouselImagesContainer.scrollLeft -= carousels[0].clientWidth)
        } else {
            console.log("GO 1 SLIDE FORWARD")
            window.requestAnimationFrame(carouselImagesContainer.scrollLeft += carousels[0].clientWidth)

        }
    })
})
```

EDIT: Below is the google guide that shows to add `touchmove` and `touchend` within `touchstart`, which is why i have them there

[image]

Comment: there may be some other listeners interrupting have you tried css such as https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/touch-action

Comment: The way you have set it up, whenever the `touchstart` event fires, you are repeatedly adding more listeners for `touchmove` and `touchend`. You should only be adding those listeners once.

Comment: @kmoser hmm, interesting.  I was following along a Google guide and they said to "Bind late"..meaning to add `touchmove` and `touchend` inside of `touchstart` ....adding the image to my post now

Comment: @kmoser added to my post now

Comment: @MauirceA The screenshot you provided is not very useful. I suggest you replace it with a link to the actual tutorial, or even better, include the relevant wording from the tutorial which suggest you do it the way you did it. Meanwhile, I still assert that your event listener should not be adding more event listeners.